# C++ casting to derived and parent structs

Tags: c++, casting

I was wondering how to do something in C++. I want to be able to create an instance of this struct

```
struct ComplexInstruction : simple_instr
{
    bool isHead;
    bool isTail;
};
```

that copies all the data from the simple_instr instance. So essentially, I want to do something like this

```
ComplexInstruction cInstr = instr; // <- instance of simple_instr
```

and have cInstr have a copy of all the data in instr without having to copy over every field (since there's alot of them). I'm not sure how do this, and I don't think simple casting will work. Additionally, is it possible to do the reverse? I.e. have an instance of ComplexInstruction and turn it into an instance of simple_instr. I assume this can be done using casting, but I don;t have alot of experience with c++

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a consctructor in the derived class to initialize from a base class.

```
class Base
{
  int x;
public:
  Base(int a) : x(a){}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived(const Base & B) : Base(B){}
};
```

Note that if you have a derived object of Base, you actually have a base object and you can safely use the base copy ctor like so.

```
Derived d;
Base b(d);//the parts of Base that are in Derived are now copied from d to b.
          //Rest is ignored.
```

If you want to be more verbose, you write an operator= in your derived class like

```
void operator=(const Base & b)
{
  Base::operator=(b);
  //don't forget to initialize the rest of the derived members after this, though.
}
```

It all depends on what you want to do, really. The important thing is: be explicit. Don't leave uninitialized members of your class.

Comment: This assumes that the default copy ctor provided by base is good enough. If it isn't, you need to define another.

Comment: +1 Still, this is by far the best solution (in fact the only one that is correct). The potential issue with the default copy constructor of the base not being sufficient is a problem in itself and unrelated to this particular question. (A slight improvement would be using the initialization list instead of assignment in the body of the `Base` copy constructor)

Comment: The solution is fine, but often you want one-parameter non-copy constructors to be explicit.

Comment: I should mention that in my edit, the word "explicit" does not mean the same as what Philipp uses.

Comment: @Philipp: Often true, but the OP specifically asked for an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Fred: Uh, not necessarily, he just said "I want to do something like this [implicit conversion]", but an explicit conversion might be fine as well.

Comment: @Philipp: That's stretching it a bit thin, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a constructor that takes an argument that is convertible to `const simple_instr&`:

```
struct simple_instr {
  int i;
  simple_instr(): i(0) { }
  explicit simple_instr(int i): i(i) { }
};

struct ComplexInstruction: simple_instr {
  explicit ComplexInstruction(const simple_instr& simple):
    simple_instr(simple), isHead(false), isTail(false) { }
  bool isHead;
  bool isTail;
};

int main() {
  simple_instr instr;
  ComplexInstruction cInstr(instr);
}
```

Here I chose an explicit constructor, but depending on the semantics, an implicit one could also be appropriate. Only if the constructor is implicit, the `=`-style initialization works without casting.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This is not the best way to accomplish this, please look at the other answers.

---

This will do what you are looking for.

```
struct ComplexInstruction : simple_instr
{
    ComplexInstruction(const simple_instr &simple)
    {
       *((simple_instr*)this) = simple;
    }

    bool isHead;
    bool isTail;
};
```

Then `ComplexInstruciton complex = simple;` will  call the conversion constructor.  ComplexInstruction's copy construct casts `this` to its base class and the = will call `simple_instr's` copy constructor, which by default is a bitwise copy.

Comment: That's funny because I just tried that coincidentally, gave me a stack overflow exception :)

Comment: Doh! Of course it would we're *this = simple calls the copy constructor.

Comment: Ok, edited with a cast to the base type in the constructor and tested it in VS2010

Comment: It does end up in infinite recursion => stack overflow. The issue is that when the compiler sees the line: `*this = simple;` it tries to match it with `operator=` at the current level, and that takes a `ComplexInstruction` as argument *luckily* (??) for the compiler it finds that it can instantiate a `ComplexInstruction` from a `simple_instr` by calling the constructor that we are defining... A simple solution is changing the line into: `simple_instr::operator=( simple );`.

Comment: much simpler to just have ComplexInstruction(const simple_instr& simple) : simple_instr(simple) {}

Comment: @diverscuba23 - yes you are correct.  What I did didn't feel right.  This really shouldn't be the accepted answer, Phillip's or San Jacinto are better.  I'd delete it but I can't since it's been accepted